# Create Voronoi art with rounded region edges

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, voronoi, generative-art

I'm trying to create some artistic "plots" like the ones below:[image: Red Voronoi art]
[image]

The color of the regions do not really matter, what I'm trying to achieve is the variable "thickness" of the edges along the Voronoi regions (espescially, how they look like a bigger rounded blob where they meet in corners, and thinner at their middle point).

I've tried by "painting manually" each pixel based on the minimum distance to each centroid (each associated with a color):

```
n_centroids = 10
centroids = [(random.randint(0, h), random.randint(0, w)) for _ in range(n_centroids)]
colors = np.array([np.random.choice(range(256), size=3) for _ in range(n_centroids)]) / 255

for x, y in it.product(range(h), range(w)):
    distances = np.sqrt([(x - c[0])**2 + (y - c[1])**2 for c in centroids])
    centroid_i = np.argmin(distances)
    img[x, y] = colors[centroid_i]
    
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

[image: voronoi diagram]

Or by `scipy.spatial.Voronoi`, that also gives me the vertices points, although I still can't see how I can draw a line through them with the desired variable thickness.

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

# make up data points
points = [(random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)) for _ in range(10)]

# add 4 distant dummy points
points = np.append(points, [[999,999], [-999,999], [999,-999], [-999,-999]], axis = 0)

# compute Voronoi tesselation
vor = Voronoi(points)

# plot
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)

# colorize
for region in vor.regions:
    if not -1 in region:
        polygon = [vor.vertices[i] for i in region]
        plt.fill(*zip(*polygon))

# fix the range of axes
plt.xlim([-2,12]), plt.ylim([-2,12])
plt.show()
```

[image: voronoi region plot]

## Edit:

I've managed to get a somewhat satisfying result via erosion + corner smoothing (via median filter as suggested in the comments) on each individual region, then drawing it into a black background.

```
res = np.zeros((h,w,3))
for color in colors:
    region = (img == color)[:,:,0]
    region = region.astype(np.uint8) * 255
    region = sg.medfilt2d(region, 15) # smooth corners
    # make edges from eroding regions
    region = cv2.erode(region, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))
    region = region.astype(bool)
    res[region] = color
    
plt.imshow(res)
```

[image: voronoi art]
But as you can see the "stretched" line along the boundaries/edges of the regions is not quite there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: For every corner of a voronoi cell you could define the maximum distance of the drawn cell to be x% shorter than the actual distance to the voronoi cell center.

Comment: Another option is to represent each voronoi cell as a dense contour (every pixel of the cell border) and to perform a contour smoothing by replacing each contour point by the average of its N neighbors. This should let the cell shrink in the corners. Afterwards draw the cell over a black background.

Comment: You could try the second answer of [radius in polygon edges - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270673/matplotlib-radius-in-polygon-edges-is-it-possible)

Comment: Thank you everyone! I managed to get some improvement and some partial result, but the visual appeal is not quite there yet. I've made an edit to the question to add the new details

Comment: I'm starting to think that the key idea is to erode "more" near the corners, and getting the region more smoothed out/"circular" as one approaches a corner. Could something like bezier polygon "approximations" help me with this?

Comment: So an answer that generates that kind of art is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! as I wrote above, something that will produce the type of lines I'm struggling with

Comment: @rikyeah In your first test example how are you defining 'img'?

Comment: @spal black image/matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what @JohanC suggestion looks like. IMO, it looks much better than my attempt with Bezier curves. <s>However, there appears to be a small problem with the `RoundedPolygon` class, as there are sometimes small defects at the corners (e.g. between blue and purple in the image below).</s>

##### Edit: I fixed the RoundedPolygon class.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061965/create-voronoi-art-with-rounded-region-edges
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import patches, path
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d


def shrink(polygon, pad):
    center = np.mean(polygon, axis=0)
    resized = np.zeros_like(polygon)
    for ii, point in enumerate(polygon):
        vector = point - center
        unit_vector = vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)
        resized[ii] = point - pad * unit_vector
    return resized


class RoundedPolygon(patches.PathPatch):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/66279687/2912349
    def __init__(self, xy, pad, **kwargs):
        p = path.Path(*self.__round(xy=xy, pad=pad))
        super().__init__(path=p, **kwargs)

    def __round(self, xy, pad):
        n = len(xy)

        for i in range(0, n):

            x0, x1, x2 = np.atleast_1d(xy[i - 1], xy[i], xy[(i + 1) % n])

            d01, d12 = x1 - x0, x2 - x1
            l01, l12 = np.linalg.norm(d01), np.linalg.norm(d12)
            u01, u12 = d01 / l01, d12 / l12

            x00 = x0 + min(pad, 0.5 * l01) * u01
            x01 = x1 - min(pad, 0.5 * l01) * u01
            x10 = x1 + min(pad, 0.5 * l12) * u12
            x11 = x2 - min(pad, 0.5 * l12) * u12

            if i == 0:
                verts = [x00, x01, x1, x10]
            else:
                verts += [x01, x1, x10]

        codes = [path.Path.MOVETO] + n*[path.Path.LINETO, path.Path.CURVE3, path.Path.CURVE3]

        verts[0] = verts[-1]

        return np.atleast_1d(verts, codes)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # make up data points
    n = 100
    max_x = 20
    max_y = 10
    points = np.c_[np.random.uniform(0, max_x, size=n),
                   np.random.uniform(0, max_y, size=n)]

    # add 4 distant dummy points
    points = np.append(points, [[2 * max_x, 2 * max_y],
                                [   -max_x, 2 * max_y],
                                [2 * max_x,    -max_y],
                                [   -max_x,    -max_y]], axis = 0)

    # compute Voronoi tesselation
    vor = Voronoi(points)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(max_x, max_y))
    for region in vor.regions:
        if region and (not -1 in region):
            polygon = np.array([vor.vertices[i] for i in region])
            resized = shrink(polygon, 0.15)
            ax.add_patch(RoundedPolygon(resized, 0.2, color=plt.cm.Reds(0.5 + 0.5*np.random.rand())))

    ax.axis([0, max_x, 0, max_y])
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_facecolor('black')
    ax.add_artist(ax.patch)
    ax.patch.set_zorder(-1)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

> Could something like bezier polygon "approximations" help me with this?

An attempt using Bezier curves:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061965/create-voronoi-art-with-rounded-region-edges
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
from bezier.curve import Curve # https://bezier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/index.html


def get_bezier(polygon, n=10):
    closed_polygon = np.concatenate([polygon, [polygon[0]]])
    # Insert additional points lying along the edges of the polygon;
    # this allows us to use higher order bezier curves.
    augmented_polygon = np.array(augment(closed_polygon, n))
    # The bezier package does not seem to support closed bezier curves;
    # to simulate a closed bezier curve, we triplicate the polygon,
    # and only evaluate the curve on the inner third.
    triplicated_polygon = np.vstack([augmented_polygon, augmented_polygon, augmented_polygon])
    bezier_curve = Curve(triplicated_polygon.T, degree=len(triplicated_polygon)-1)
    return bezier_curve.evaluate_multi(np.linspace(1./3, 2./3, 100)).T


def augment(polygon, n=10):
    new_points = []
    for ii, (x0, y0) in enumerate(polygon[:-1]):
        x1, y1 = polygon[ii+1]
        x = np.linspace(x0, x1, n)
        y = np.linspace(y0, y1, n)
        new_points.extend(list(zip(x[:-1], y[:-1])))
    new_points.append((x1, y1))
    return new_points


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # make up data points
    points = np.random.randint(0, 11, size=(50, 2))

    # add 4 distant dummy points
    points = np.append(points, [[999,999], [-999,999], [999,-999], [-999,-999]], axis = 0)

    # compute Voronoi tesselation
    vor = Voronoi(points)
    # voronoi_plot_2d(vor)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for region in vor.regions:
        if region and (not -1 in region):
            polygon = np.array([vor.vertices[i] for i in region])
            bezier_curve_points = get_bezier(polygon, 40)
            ax.fill(*zip(*bezier_curve_points))

    ax.axis([1, 9, 1, 9])
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! looks very good! Increasing the value of n over 40 leaves some empty spots, what might be the reason?

Comment: The `bezier.curve.Curve` sometimes fails with a cryptic error message if the distance between any two points is too small.

Comment: This answer was more an illustration of what it would look like with Bezier curves (as using them was my first instinct as well). After playing around a bit, I think that @johanc has the better suggestion.