# How to create voronoi art using python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a simple voronoi image based on another stackoverflow question I've seen: [Create Voronoi art with rounded region edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061965/create-voronoi-art-with-rounded-region-edges)

In the first example the user provides, he is "painting manually" each pixel based on the minimum distance to each centroid (each associated with a color). I have tried replicating his code but am having some trouble.

Voronoi.py:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_centroids = 10
h = 5
w = 5
x = 5
y = 5
img = [x,y]

centroids = [(random.randint(0, h), random.randint(0, w)) for _ in range(n_centroids)]
colors = np.array([np.random.choice(range(256), size=3) for _ in range(n_centroids)]) / 255
    
for x, y in it.product(range(h), range(w)):
    distances = np.sqrt([(x - c[0])**2 + (y - c[1])**2 for c in centroids])
    centroid_i = np.argmin(distances)
    img[x,y] = colors[centroid_i]

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

When I try to assign `img[x,y] = colors[centroid_i]`, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I believe it is due to how I am declaring img but cannot quite figure it out.

This is what the end result should look like:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with `img = [x,y]`? That doesn't look like an image.

Comment: Right.  You almost certainly wanted `img = np.zeroes((x,y,3))`.